# Compute Spearman correlation with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I have to compute the Spearman correlation between the `(name, score)` `list` that I have computed, when sorted by descending score.

You can assume there are no tied ranks, which means that the simpler form of the Spearman calculation can be used.

Can I compute that without using `scipy`? I have tried using `scipy.stats` module but nothing happened. I am okay with using `scipy` too.

```
 import scipy.stats
 x=[['x',0.212],['a', 0.324],['s', -2.432], ['b',0.2342],['x', -3.232]]
 def spearman(l):
    c = []
    for i in l:
         c.append(scipy.stats.pearsonr(i,i+1))
    return c
 computed_spearman = spearman(x)
```

I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 2, in
>    TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: The error is due to the expression i+1. i will be a list, e.g. ['x', 0.212], in your first iteration and i+1 will try to append 1 to the list. Did you mean to take the ith element if the list?

Comment: Also I don't see why you use pearsonr instead of spearmanr and how pandas fits in with all of this. Maybe you could rephrase your question to clearify what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute spearman correlation using pandas you can do it as follow:

```
import pandas as pd

x = [['x',0.212], ['a', 0.324], ['s', -2.432], ['b',0.2342], ['x', -3.232]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=x)
df.corr(method='spearman')
```

However, I don't see how this makes any sense for your data. Maybe you could clarify your intent.